# Select "Android X.X" or "Google APIs" in new project

Tags: android, build, targets

I think it's basically the same, but what build target should I select? Or is there really difference between them?

For example the "Android 2.2" or "Google APIs" for the same Platform and API Level?

[image: Eclipse Build Target selector]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you application uses a google API, such as Google Maps, you will need the Google API version. I have not encountered a commercial device that does not include that build, but the raw open source Android does not include the Google API because it contains proprietary non-open source code from google.

If you do not use any of these API's it will not matter which one you choose. But if you are using any of the google apis you must use the google build.

Comment: mark - if you click "accept" when you have an answer, you will get a better response rate when you ask questions in the future. If this answers you question, please click accept so the question is closed.

Comment: Just for information : what changes required to the emulator , while selecting either google api or android open source project?

Answer (score 0):

It will matter for some things, if you select a newer API you need to be careful what methods you use in your program.

if you use a method that is new in 3.2 and doesnt exist in older API's your app will not run on older devices...unless you make exceptions

Comment: probably haven't explained well. I ask if it does matter if I select "Android 2.2" or "Google APIs for platform 2.2", which is basically the same API level

Comment: sorry, you must have installed extra packs as I dont have these options. These are Google's API's and will be used for Google Maps development and such like...not android stuff